# C# Outlook AddIn - Cannot seem to access shared mailbox

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I've written a add-in for outlook 2007 in .NET 4.0, C#. The addin simply does some manipulation to the subject for any incoming email.

This add-in works in my 'test environment', which is basically an offline outlook account, but it does not work when I try to do the same thing but on a shared mailbox.  Are there any special considerations that need to be made when trying to work with a shared mailbox?

Hopefully the isn't too generic...  Thanks

Edit: By "doesn't work", I should clarify that it simply does nothing.  It doens't crash anything, throw an exception or anything like that.... This is what makes me think that it doesn't recognize the folder, as its basically the first step in the code

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work"?  Does it throw an exception?  Crash outlook?  Randomly send emails asking for help laundering money from Nigeria?

Comment: haha, wish it was sending Nigeria.  It actually just doens't do anything.  Doesnt crash, doesn't throw any exceptions etc.  It just does nadda.  Which is what makes me think that its not recognizing the folder, as that's the first step...

Comment: Sounds like you need to add some logging then, to see whether it is just failing to see the folder or what.

Comment: How would I do that? What makes it tough is I don't have VS2010 on the 'production' computer, so I can't just throw a stop into the code....

Comment: You can use a library like log4net or NLog to add logging to a file.  Then run it on the production computer, and examine what gets written.